# PDfs in Automator

Tags: macos, pdf, automation

I work in photography post production, need to make PDFs from images but with the file names shown on the PDF and 4 up instead of a single image on each page.

Can anyone suggest additional plugins or scripting language I can implement into the automator?

Comment: Where to want to print the photos from, Finder or a specific application? What have you tried so far, either regarding the print option in said application, any other application or attempts in Automator?

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following Shortcuts workflow. It's a bit clunky but does the job.[image]

Answer (score -1):

Automator lacks sophisticated tools to impose 4 images on a page. Surely you have Photoshop? You should be able to create an Action to do this: even creating 2 x 2 Thumbnails would work.